# Image and binary method return type

Tags: java, android

So there is this project that I'm working on from school.
It is based on calling a method dynamically in android. I'm calling the invoke method.
Now there is something in the project requirements that I still don't understand.
Print out the type of the returned object, it could be an Image, a String, or a binary.
I'm not quite sure if I understand that, there is no Image or Binary type in android. Is there?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can return either a [Uri](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html) and decode it in next method, or return a [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html).